# How to configure Java heap size for node.js JDBC module?

Tags: java, node.js, jdbc

In my node.js application, I'm using [JDBC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) to connect to a Oracle database. I need to increase my java heap space to prevent following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know that there is a terminal option for setting maximum Java heap size (`-Xmx<size>`) but the problem is, I don't explicitly run java, it happens inside my JDBC module (which depends on [java module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java)), so I can't use that terminal option.

So how java heap size can be configured in my case?

Comment: Have you tried: `jinst.addOption("-Xmx1024");` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short**

I checked the source code of `node-jdbc`, and it's not possible at the moment.

---

**In Detail**

Refer the file `jinst.js`

```
var java = require('java');
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  addOption: function(option) {
    if (!isJvmCreated() && option) {
      java.options.push(option);
    } else if (isJvmCreated()) {
    ...
```

Refer the files `pool.js, connection.js, resultset.js`

```
var jinst = require("./jinst");
...
var java = jinst.getInstance();
...
if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
}
```

You will see it's only setting the option `-Xrs` even though the node module java is giving the flexibility of adding any java options.

**Next Step**

For the moment I'm not interested in this project. But If I was in your shoes I will create a pull request to the project https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc with this option as a feature.

Cheers :)